# Convert units in a netcdf file efficiently

Tags: r

I have netcdf data with precipitation units in kg m-2 s-1. I want to convert it to mm. (1 kg/m2/s = 86400 mm/day)
my plan would be to change the data to a dataframe and then go over each cell.
is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the terra package. It was made to work with raster data and most of its routines are memory safe and quite fast since it is written in C++ instead of pure R.

You can probably do something like this

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("file.nc") 
y <- x * 86400
```